# Access constant in an Ember template

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Not sure what the proper "Ember Way" is to do this.

I have the following template, where I want to have three `task-item-list` component instances, each for a different `taskState` value.  Obviously, I would like to get rid of the magic numbers.

```
<h4>Tasks:</h4>

<div><h5>Backlog:</h5>
  {{ task-item-list tasks=model taskState=101 }}
</div>

<div><h5>Working:</h5>
  {{ task-item-list tasks=model taskState=202 }}
</div>

<div><h5>Done!</h5>
  {{ task-item-list tasks=model taskState=303 }}
</div>
```

Thanks to [this discussion](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/custom-env-vars-in-ember-cli/6491/20) I can define constants in my `config/environment.js` file and use them in models, test, etc., but not (as near as I can tell) in my templates.

Is there a way to use the constants, or is there a better way to do this?  I can see subclassing the component, but I don't think that's a great solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried to inject the env in your components? Something like this:

*app/initializers/inject-env.js*

```
import env from '../config/environment';

export function initialize(container, application) {
  application.register('env:main', env, { singleton: true, instantiate: false });
  application.inject('component', 'env', 'env:main');
}

export default {
  name: 'inject-env',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

And then in any component you will be able to get the contents of `config/environment.js` using the `env` property. For instance `{{env.environment}}` will show the current environment.

If you want to inject just in your `task-item-list` component instead of all components, you can use:

`application.inject('component:task-item-list', 'env', 'env:main');`

Comment: Fantastic, thanks!  That works well, with the caveat that I had to make my template above its own component, so it could "see" the injection.  More research on my part now...

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem and solved it by creating a helper, that can read configuration file:

```
//...app/helpers/read-env.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import ENV from '../config/environment';

export function readEnv(params/*, hash*/) {
  if (params.length === 0) {
    return undefined;
  }

  return Ember.Object.create(ENV).get(params[0]);
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(readEnv);
```

Constants defined like this:

```
ENV.CATEGORY = {
  'CATEGORY_1': 0,
  'CATEGORY_2': 1
};
```

In template I use it like this:

```
{{read-env 'CATEGORY.CATEGORY_1'}}
```