# In my Ember.js app, how can I define a global config value that can be referenced in my templates?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I would like to define a global config value that I can reference in my Ember.js templates. The value is our support email address. Is there a way to add this to the environment config so that I can reference it in a template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `/config/environment.js` to store global config properties. You can access these values from js files such as:

```
 import Config from '/<app-name>/config/environment';

 export default Ember.Component.extend({
     myProperty: Ember.computed(function(){
         return Config.myProperty;
     }),

     ....
 });
```

You can use this property in your component's template.

You can also write a helper that access this property from config and supply the value to your templates.

Read more from [Ember Guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/configuring-ember/configuring-your-app/)

Comment: So there's no way to access the config values without writing a custom helper?

Comment: There is another way: [Look at that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28903727/4545506). Also the other answer on that question is writing a *helper*

Comment: I would recommend to import the config in your `controller` or `component` as in this answer and then place it on a property and use that in your template.

Comment: I seem to be having trouble importing the config. I've tried several variations of `import ENV from '/frontend/config/environment.js';` and still see the error: Could not find module `frontend/config/environment.js` imported from `frontend/controllers/account`. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?